Global minimum weighted vertext cut for undirected graphs
Given an undirected graph with vertex weights, there any algorithm for finding the global minimum vertex cut that partitions the graph into two components?
I can transform the graph to directed one and use a repeated edge min-cut algorithm, but is there a better way (something like Karger's algorithm or Stoer-Wagner algorthm)?

You mean something like this? Deterministic Near-Linear Time Minimum Cut in Weighted Graphs

You can read about this very new result on the blog post Solving the minimum cut problem for undirected graphs.

This paper talks about edge cuts. I want to avoid using edge cuts on directed graphs because I would still need to run it repeatedly.

Oh, you're talking about separators

Yes. I'm trying to find a vertex separator
